# Kurt Schutte Proof Theory (Theorem 1.5 proof)

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I had a question regarding the proof of Theorem 1.5 in Kurt Schutte's Proof Theory.

**Theorem 1.5** If $\mathcal{E}$ is a $P$-form and $V$ a sentential valuation with $VA = t$, then $V \mathcal{E}[A] = t$.

We proceed by induction on the length of $\mathcal{E}$. The first part is clear, if $\mathcal{E}$ is of the form $*_1$, then $V\mathcal{E}[A] = V *_1 [A] = VA = t$ since we replace each occurrence of $*_1$ in $*_1$ with $A$ and the result is just $A$. However, if $\mathcal{E}$ is of the form $\mathcal{P}[(*_1 \vee B)]$ where $\mathcal{P}$ is a $P$-form and $B$ is a formula, then how would  I evaluate and justify $V \mathcal{P}[(*_1 \vee B)][A]$ to arrive at $V[(A \vee B)] = t$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to math.SE!

Formally, what we're trying to establish is equivalent to the following:

> For any sentential valuation $V$, it is the case that for every P-form $\mathcal{E}$, the following holds: for any $A$, if $VA = t$ then $V\mathcal{E}[A] = t$.

Hence, we can fix a sentential valuation $V$ and take the induction hypothesis to be the following:

> For any P-form $\mathcal{P}$ that is strictly shorter than $\mathcal{E}$, the following holds: for any $A$, if $VA = t$ then $V\mathcal{P}[A] = t$.

Now, we need to prove that the same conclusion holds for $\mathcal{E}$, i.e.

> for any $X$, if $VX = t$ then $V\mathcal{E}[X] = t$.

We deal with the case when $\mathcal{E}$ can be written in the form $\mathcal{P}[*_1 \vee B]$ for some $\mathcal{P}$. Then $\mathcal{P}$ is shorter than $\mathcal{E}$, so the induction hypothesis gives us the following:

> For any $A$, if $VA = t$ then $V\mathcal{P}[A] = t$.

Consider any $X$, and set $A=X \vee B$. From $V(X) = t$ it follows that $V(X\vee B) = t$, so by the induction hypothesis we have that $V\mathcal{P}[X \vee B] = t$. But then we get $$V\mathcal{E}[X] = V(\mathcal{P}[*_1 \vee B])[X] = V\mathcal{P}[X \vee B] = t$$
as desired (the second equality follows by definition of substitution on top of page 11).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I had one other question regarding this same problem. If we consider the case where $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{N}[(\neg *_1)]$ which is a $P$-form, then our induction hypothesis does not hold since $\mathcal{N}$ is an $N$-form, and we are assuming that every $P$-form of length less than $\mathcal{E}$ has the desired property. What should the induction hypothesis be in this case in order to show that $V \mathcal{N}[(\neg *_1)][A] = V \mathcal{N}[(\neg A)]=t$?

Comment: The full statement the book is proving is that "if $\mathcal{E}$ is a P-form (N-form) and $V$ a sentential valuation with $VA = t$ ($VA=f$), then $V\mathcal{E}[X]=t$. You have these parenthetical N-form cases in the induction hypothesis as well. 

The induction hypothesis includes "for all $A$", that's why Schütte can take an arbitrary $A$, then apply the induction hypothesis with $\neg A$ in the fourth case.